# How to get the base table column in inside joinWith() yii2

Tags: php, mysql, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-model

Order and OrderProducts. How to get the order table column joinWith().

```
      Order::find()
        ->select(['order.*'])
        ->joinWith(['orderProducts' => function($q){
                $q->select("order_id, product_id, product_name, product_price, quantity, CONCAT(order.currency, total_price) AS total_price");
            }])
```

In the above query it shows this error:

```
 SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'order.currency' in 'field list'\nThe SQL being executed was: SELECT order.currency, id, CONCAT('http://192.168.1.114:1090/backend/web/images/products/',image) AS image, sku FROM `POS_1hj2gfru`.`product` WHERE `id`='3'"
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use

```
Order::find()
    ->select(["order.*","orderProducts.order_id" , "orderProducts.product_id" , "orderProducts.product_name" , "orderProducts.product_price" , "orderProducts.quantity" , "orderProducts.CONCAT(orderProducts.order.currency, orderProducts.total_price) AS total_price"])
    ->joinWith('orderProducts', false)
    ->asArray()
    ->all();
```

Comment: Is it possible to get in eagerLoading?

Comment: In my question i used eagerloading only but its shows column not found error. Can you tell how can i do that?

Comment: Ya i have tried. But when i doing like that my output format will be changed . That's why i using  eagerloading. In that sql, order have one column and order products will be multiple

Comment: so remove  ->asArray() , it will give output in array format ,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109667/discussion-between-sivabalan-and-brijal-savaliya).